# Azure AD not resolving Angularjs $state.go changes

Tags: angularjs, adal

I am trying to use Azure AD v1.0.14 in a pre-existing Angularjs application which uses ui.router to manage state changes. The good news is that I can login and logout successfully, but the bad news is that my app is having issues managing state changes. These state changes worked before I integrated Azure AD module into the code.

```
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, adalProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
        console.log("Requested URL path=" + $location.$$path);
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.when('/home', '/home/app');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/app', '/home/app');            
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
        console.log('$urlRouterProvider.otherwise redirecting to ' + $location.$$path);
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go("login");
    });

    $stateProvider
         .state("login", ...)
         .state("home", {
             abstract: true,
             url: '/home',
             requireADLogin: false,
             templateUrl: 'home.html'
         })
         .state("app", {
             url: '/app',
             requireADLogin: false,
             templateUrl: 'app.html',
             controller: 'app'
         })
         .state("more", ...)

}
```

Initially, entry successfully goes to the login in state/controller (where I login/logout), but attempts to $state.go('app') or a manual URL entry to 'http://baseurl/#/home/app' are automatically redirected back to 'login' via the .otherwise rule, and it appears that this is done by Azure AD as per the log output below.

```
Wed, 01 Mar 2017 22:56:38 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: Location change event from http://localhost:3000/#/login to http://localhost:3000/#/home @state.js:12 
Requested URL path=/home @app.js:14 
Wed, 01 Mar 2017 22:56:38 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: Location change event from http://localhost:3000/#/home to http://localhost:3000/#/home/app @state.js:12   
Requested URL path=/home/app @state.js:19 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise redirecting to /home/app @app.js:14 
Wed, 01 Mar 2017 22:56:38 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: Location change event from http://localhost:3000/#/home/app to http://localhost:3000/#/login @state.js:12 
Requested URL path=/login @state.js:12
```

My question is why would Azure AD redirect back to login? Can Azure AD not handle abstract/nested states? Is there a work around for this because our home state is essential.

Comment: Hi HidefLolife, do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

As the url pattern after hash "#" is for client, server will not handle these part and which will be ignored in redirect url, you can try to use `html5` mode in angularjs:

```
// using '!' as the hashPrefix but can be a character of your choosing
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

> Can Azure AD not handle abstract/nested states?

You can add `anonymousEndpoints` in adal for js's configuration, like:

```
adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init({
    tenant: TENANT_ID,
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    anonymousEndpoints: ['public/'] //will not authorize for public pattern 
  },
```

You can find more info at the 6 point of https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js#getting-started.